# Is there any load when reading EEPROM inside SFP module?

Tags: sfp, ethtool

I am trying to measure the optical receving/transmitting levels with ethtool on the server.
It was confirmed that ethtool reads information from EEPROM inside the SFP module.

1. When a read operation to check the optical level occurs in the EEPROM, what kind of load occurs?
2. When does an SFP or SFP-like optical module store information in EEPROM?

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is memory, not all memory is in EEPROM, sometimes none. There should be no load, if you have multiple processes trying to read data then the NIC driver should make sure the requests are properly queued.

[SFF-8472](https://web.archive.org/web/20170317055100/https://ta.snia.org/kws/public/download/294/SFF-8472.PDF) should describe the details.